# c# Update Command to Access Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to update data in access table. However, i keep receiving a syntax error when i attempt to update. Below is the code ive compiled. Textbox37 is the one that requires updates.

```
string constr1;

constr1 = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\\Documents\\data.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database";

string cmdstr = "Update Log(Notes,Status)Values(@a,@b) Where LogIncNum='" + LogInc + "'";

using (OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(constr1))
{
    using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con1))
    {
        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                       
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", textBox37.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", "Active");

        con1.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Also: `OleDbCommand` doesn't support **named** parameters `@a`, `@b` etc - it only supports `?` as a positional placeholder for a parameter

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for an update statement is

```
UPDATE table SET field1=value1, field2=value2 WHERE field3=value3
```

You are using the wrong syntax hence the syntax error

As a side note, did you forget to use a parameter for the WHERE condition?
It is always correct to use a parameter for every value that you want to include in your query. Just remember to put it in the correct order because OleDb doesn't recognize the parameter by their name, but use a strictly positional order in the Parameters collection, so the first one goes assigned to the first parameter placeholder and so on.

Answer (score 0):

easy way

```
using (var aq_pension = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource())
        {
            aq_pension.ProviderName = "System.Data.OleDb";
            aq_pension.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:/stat_tresor/stat_tresor/stat_tresor/db/stat1.mdb";

            aq_pension.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE tableaux1 SET nbre=0, montant_mois=0,total=0 WHERE code <>''";

            aq_pension.Update();
        }
```